# Which is the better way of generating a salt string?

Tags: salt

Using T-SQL as per the snippets below, which method is superior (or is it a tie)?

````
 -- method 1: DIY 
 SET @Salt = ''
 WHILE LEN(@Salt) < 72
 BEGIN
   SET @Salt = @Salt + CHAR(CONVERT(INT, Floor(RAND() * (126.0 - 33 + 1) + 33)))
 END


 -- method 2: concatenating 2 GUIDs
 SET @Salt = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID())```
````

Comment: Now at least we can have `Robert');DROP TABLE Students;-- ` in a salt. See [obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/), and [this](https://explainxkcd.com/327/) if you don't quite get it. Worry about unpredictability of `RAND()` and `NEWID()` in whatever the environment is. What `CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID())` does is language-dependent, thus off-topic.

Comment: What is the usage of this salt?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. The `RAND` function in method 1 isn't cryptographically random; the GUID generation is only random with version 4, and isn't guaranteed to be of cryptographic quality.